# Replacing a property of an object in JSON array of based on another property value

Tags: json, regex, replace

I am writing a regex rule for a debugging proxy (could also apply to processing text in Notepad++ or something like that).

I have an array of objects in JSON form and I need to replace one of the values of an object if their other property value matches

```
[
    { "name": "alpha", /* a lot of omitted properties */, "foo": "bar", /* a lot of omitted properties */},
    { "name": "beta", /* a lot of omitted properties */, "foo": "baz", /* a lot of omitted properties */ },
    { "name": "gamma", /* a lot of omitted properties */, "foo": "bat", /* a lot of omitted properties */ }
]
```

In this example I want regex to match objects where foo = baz and replace their name with `replacedName`, so replacement pattern could be like `$1replacedName$2`

I tried this: ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/gMfXCU/1))

```
({\s*"name":\s*")(?:\w+)"([\S\s]+?"foo":\s*"baz".*?})
```

But then the expression matches 1st and 2nd objects, and name of 1st is replaced. How do I make regex stop evaluating next objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make sure you never match the closing curly bracket of JSON `}` - so instead of using stuff like `[\S\s]*?` or `.*?`, be more specific and use `[^}]*?`: ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/gMfXCU/2))

```
({\s*"name":\s*")(?:\w+)("[^}]+?"foo":\s*"baz".*?})
```

Some improvements: make it work with nested objects in between; remove unnecessary match on start and end of the object: ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/gMfXCU/5))

```
("name":\s*"\s*)(?:[^"]+)("[^}]*?(?:\{[^}]*?\}[^}]*?)*?"foo"\s*:\s*"baz")
```

And if the search term would be before the value that needs to be replaced, the expression would be: ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/gMfXCU/6))

```
("foo"\s*:\s*"baz"[^}]*?(?:\{[^}]*?\}[^}]*?)*?"name":\s*"\s*)(?:[^"]+)(")
```

In both cases, replacement is the same `$1replacedName$2`